# Add maven docsets to zeal

Tags: scala, maven, zeal

According to the [dash website](https://kapeli.com/dash#thirdparty) there are maven docsets available. How do I add them to zeal?

Answer (score 5):

Zeal has a (Tools -> Docsets -> Add feed) option to add external docsets but I was unable to find the feeds for the maven.org docsets.

That being said, you can add feeds for user-contributed docsets - perhaps that will have the docs you're looking for? I found two options for getting the user-contributed docset feed URLs:

- Search via https://zealusercontributions.herokuapp.com/
- Get the URL to the raw XML on github at https://github.com/zsoltika/feeds

These are not officially supported by the zeal/dash maintainers so **use at your own risk!** I found these solutions in the ["Show Dash user contrib docsets in Zeal" github issue](https://github.com/zealdocs/zeal/issues/170).

You might be able to [generate the docsets yourself](https://kapeli.com/docsets) but, in looking around the app UI, I found no intuitive way to get that into zeal either.